# Induction on the complexity of PL formula

Tags: logic

I am reading Shawn Hedman's First Course in Logic. The author first states that when performing induction on the complexity of a formula $H$, one needs to show in the induction step the effects of not just $\neg$ and $\wedge$ but also $\vee$, $\rightarrow$, and $\leftrightarrow$. Since the other three symbols ($\vee$, $\rightarrow$, and $\leftrightarrow$) are not in the formula producing rules of Propositional Logic (PL), I think there is no need to
check their effects in the induction step. Later on when discussing CNF and DNF of PL, the author states that one actually only needs to show in the induction step just the effects of $\neg$ and $\wedge$ and to show that the theorem is preserved across equivalence $\equiv$. Because induction on the complexity of a formula $H$ relies on the syntax not the semantic of the logic, why is it necessary to show that the theorem is preserved across equivalence? Perhaps a specific example to convince me that it is really necessary to do so?

**Clarification:** The author might first want to convince that the theorem works for all 5 symbols used so far because the remaining 3 symbols are proved by referring to the proofs of $\neg$ and $\wedge$. Then, before the second case, the author states: "For the induction step, instead of verifying the five cases as above, we can *sometimes* do just three cases. First we show that $P$ is preserved under equivalence. That is, we show that if $F \equiv G$ and $G$ possess property $P$, then so does $F$." Why "sometimes"? And, why "preserved under equivalence" when only syntax is dealt with?

Comment: Your question is basically "in case 1 we have to do X, in case 2 we don't have to do X".  Do you think the details of what are case 1 and 2 might be relevant?

Comment: Correct; see page 2 : "we take the symbols ¬ and ∧ as *primitives*. We define the other symbols in terms of these two symbols." Thus, the syntactical specification for *formulae* of the language (see **Def.1.2**) consider only the two cases : *(i)* $\lnot F$ and *(ii)* $(F \land G)$.

Comment: @DanielV: I think you are correct. I edit my question for clarification. It has something to do with connecting the induction step with the induction hypothesis, which will be different for different theorems. In the first case, the theorem deals with some subformula of $H$. Hence, the induction step is already connected with the induction hypothesis by the subformula. In the second case, the theorem deals with a formula $H$ as a whole. Hence, to connect the induction step with the induction hypothesis, it is necessary to show that the theorem is preserved under equivalence. What do you think?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA: Yes, you are right. On page 27, the author wrote: "First we show that $P$ is preserved under equivalence. That is, we show that if $F \equiv G$ and $G$ possess property $P$, then so does $F$. If this is true, then we only need to consider the cases corresponding to $\neg$ and $\wedge$. This *suffices* because every formula of propositional logic is equivalent to a formula that uses only $\neg$ and $\wedge$ (and **neither** $\vee$, $\rightarrow$, **nor** $\leftrightarrow$)."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although a logic may define abbreviation symbols in addition to the primitive symbols of its grammar, for example, Propositional Logic defines abbreviation symbols $\vee$, $\rightarrow$, and $\leftrightarrow$ in addition to the primitive symbols $\neg$ and $\wedge$, when proving a certain property $P$ by induction on the complexity of a formula $H$, the induction step must show that $P$ also holds when those abbreviation symbols are in use. One may argue that it is not necessary, but formally it is necessary because the symbol $\wedge$ is formally not the symbol $\vee$. Moreover, one may argue that upon encountering an abbreviation symbol in a formula $H$, it can simply be expanded to the primitive symbols, and therefore, there is no need to show that $P$ holds also for the abbreviation symbol. But again, formally the formula with such expansions is no longer $H$ but $H'$. Therefore, the induction step must show that $P$ also holds when those abbreviation symbols are in use.

*Sometimes*, if it can be shown in the induction step that the property $P$ is preserved under equivalence (i.e., if $H \equiv G$ and $G$, which usually is the induction hypothesis, has the property $P$, then $H$ has the property $P$), then it is justified to *not* show that $P$ also holds when those abbreviation symbols are in use because a formula $H$ that uses the abbreviation symbols is equivalent to another formula $H'$ that expands all of the abbreviation symbols to the primitive symbols. When proving certain theorems such as Substitution Theorem (Theorem 1.49 in the book), however, showing that a property $P$ is preserved under equivalence will create a circularity (i.e., the theorem being proven is used to prove the theorem itself). In such a situation, the induction step must show that $P$ also holds when the abbreviation symbols are in use.

Comment: I think you are trying hard to defend the indefensible. Abbreviations are abbreviations: if $A \lor B$ is defined as an abbreviation for $\lnot(\lnot A \land \lnot B)$ (say), then $A \lor B$ is not just equivalent to $\lnot(\lnot A \land \lnot B)$, it is **identical** to it and there is no need consider $A \lor B$ as a separate case in an induction over syntax. If the tax man abbreviated your name to "T. Prastowo", then you wouldn't have to pay your tax twice!

Comment: @RobArthan: Yes, that was also my thinking. But, just to be sure, I asked the question here. Based on some comment, I started to think if suppose the author had another reason. Then, the reason that I could think of is that what I wrote above. Based on your argument, do you want to say that the author also defends something indefensible, or do you want to propose another reason why the author does so?